# Will the Rode NT1-A work well with the Focusrite Scarlett 2i2?

Tags: microphone, interface

I have a YouTube cover channel and I'm just starting but the sound is not great right now because of my mic. I have decided to buy a new one and I like the NT1-A but I realize that I need an interface to connect it on my Mac.

I don't know anything about those things but the Focusrite Scarlett looks like it should work. Will this work, or should I go for the Focusrite package that also includes a mic?

Comment: They work together and actually sound quite good

Comment: Jezz - welcome. Please read our [ask] page to understand what is on and off topic. I have edited your post to keep it on topic as much as I can (although this steers very close to opinion based)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is any interface with an XLR input that provides phantom power. Either that or buy a preamp that provides it.

So that's all you need with your interface:

- XLR in (also called Canon)
- Phantom Power

I'm sure the focusrite is fine but there are hundreds of choices.

The NT1-A is a good mic, but bear in mind as it's not dynamic, it will pick up your entire room if you're not careful. So make sure you don't have tons of noise like fans in your room otherwise that will feature prominently in your recordings.